# Create Multi-Dimensional random numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I have a 4 dimensional dataset with 200 entries. I am going to generate a random values within this dataset. I declared below variables:

```
mu = median(Input,2)';    % find the median of Input as MU
sigma = [2 1; 1 4];      % SIGMA
Data = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,10)';  % Generate random number with "mvnrnd" function
```

But, MATLAB gives me an error as follows:

```
SIGMA must be a square matrix with size equal to the number of columns in MU, or a row vector with length equal to the number of columns in MU.
```

I think that, "mvnrnd" function cannot generate data more than 2D.

Could you please advice me?

Comment: 'Data(1,:) = mvnrnd(mu(1,:),sigma,10)';' and so on and so for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells ou that `mu` is not a row vector, and that's because you take the median of the rows, simply transpose it:

```
mu = median(Input,2).';
```

Here is one way to create a positive semi-definite matrice:

```
temp = rand(numel(mu));
sigma = temp.'*temp;
Data = mvnrnd(mu,sigma ,100);
```

Alternatively, you can just define `sigma` as a row vector:

```
sigma = [2 1 1 4];
```

I don't know how you choose your `sigma`, but the example above shows you it's possible to create more than 2-D Multivariate Normal Distribution with `mvnrnd`.

Comment: I did it, but the error changed to: SIGMA must be a square matrix with size equal to the number of columns in MU, or a row vector with length equal to the number of columns in MU.

Comment: and what is the size of your `mu`?

Comment: 1*4 , the size of data's features

Comment: @BlueBit see my edit for a simple case that works with more than 2-D